# Google app engine Big table database with Python desktop applications

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Just out of curiosity, do Big table can be used as back-end for data storage for DESKTOP applications(stand alone applications).

Suppose a scenario:

1. Application start and check automatically for Internet access.
2. Once connection exists, we can perform CRUD operation on Big table through application.

Is this possible? If yes,is there any documents/link available on this.

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "out of the box" to do this for you, but in theory this is no different from having a web-based GUI performing CRUD operations against the datastore. Your desktop app will still be communicating with your appengine app via HTTP requests.

- You would still have to decide on how to [structure you data in the datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling.html).
- Choose an authentication mechanism (take a look at [OAuth](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html))
- Write an API to deal with your CRUD requests (checkout [protorpc](http://code.google.com/p/google-protorpc/))
- Choose a serialization format that you will be communicating with (probably JSON)
- Write a python client to communicate with your app (protorpc makes this *really* easy)

Comment: Hello Chris,thank you for your answer. will update you soon after going through some of the suggestions.Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload and download data in CSV or XML format through the [bulk loader tool](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)hich doesn't solve your problem, w. Alternatively you could develop an API to do your remote CRUD work through.